# How to solve Numpy installing error in windows 10, (Python 64 bit)?

Tags: python, windows, numpy

I was installing numpy in python latest version 3.10.4 (64bit) after installation of python I did this below in cmd window.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>mkdir pyver

C:\Users\Administrator>mkdir pyproj


C:\Users\Administrator>cd pyproj

C:\Users\Administrator\pyproj>c:\Users\Administrator\pyver\py383\python -m venv my_env

C:\Users\Administrator\pyproj>my_env\Scripts\activate

(my_env) C:\Users\Administrator\pyproj>python
Python 3.10.4 (tags/v3.10.4:9d38120, Mar 23 2022, 23:13:41) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print('Hello world')
Hello world
>>> import numpy as np

>>> exit()

(my_env) C:\Users\Administrator\pyproj>pip install numpy

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/numpy/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/numpy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/numpy/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:997)'))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy
```

I don't understand what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install numpy on a Windows VM using the following command -

```
pip install numpy --index-url=http://pypi.python.org/simple/ --trusted-host pypi.python.org
```

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy

Comment: It could even be a network issue. Are you using any enterprise VPNs or firewalls? I faced this issue in my work computer once. 

If there is no specific need to use pip, could you try installing numpy using conda instead?